# Entity Framework error PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two Entities, Book.cs and Publisher.cs, and Context Class too, I create the CRUD of the Publisher.cs by way of Controllers (everybody ready and OK), I tried now create BookController but I get this error:

```
Could not load type 'MvcProject.Models.Publisher' from assembly 'MvcProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Comment: There should be more to the error.

Comment: Did you compile before you tried to create the BookController?  After you create a model class, you've got to build the solution so that the wizard can see the newly created model class.

Comment: No more errors, that's it. And yes I Build the application before try

Comment: I do not know if you do not understand, but I still can not generate the Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the assembly in the GAC or any place the might be overriding the assembly that you think is being loaded? This is usually the result of an incorrect assembly being loaded,

||

If you have one project referencing another project (such as a 'Windows Application' type referencing a 'Class Library') and both have the same Assembly name, you'll get this error. You can either strongly name the referenced project or (even better) rename the assembly of the referencing project (under the 'Application' tab of project properties in VS).

Comment: May be the same, because I tried many times to create this controller and looked at other tutorials, some probably should have replaced. Thank you anyway! @Leez